# Loading Assets from inside of theme folder

Tags: php, codeigniter

In trying to find out how to have the following work. I have the template library located here and I'm trying to figure out how I can have the dashboard look for the images/css/js files in the file structure below as opposed to the regular assets folder in the public_html folder since those files only pertain to that theme.

https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-template

```
/application
   /themes
      /supr
          /views
              dashboard.php
          /assets
             /js
             /css
             /images
/public_html
    /assets
        /js
        /css
        /images
    index.php
```

Anybody else have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using the same library with some modifications: https://github.com/FDiskas/MightMedia_TVS/

With structure I'm happy:

```
/themes
    /demo
        /views
            /mobile
            /web
                /layouts
                /modules
                /partials
                /resources
                    /css
                    /img
                    /js
```

In production all this css and js file are combined and compressed in to the
`application/resource/compiled` folder

demo here: http://pac.lt/en.html

Comment: Awesome. Can you email me so I can ask you a few individual questions about this, please. It would help tremendously. kevin.smith754@yahoo.com

Comment: Yes - sure - and you can still contact me at github or here or anywhere :)

Answer (score 2):

You better restructure that, that is not possible to achieve on Apache servers as `mod_rewrite` does not allow rewriting outside of the directory (one or more levels up) and you'll have to read a bunch of docs on nginx to do that if you're not familiar with rewrites. You can try to make CodeIgniter do it for you by checking if file exists in your themes folder and rendering it to output, but that will be a hell of a performance decrease as every image will call CI and will eventually rise bugs in your app.

I suggest you to use this structure instead:

```
/application
   /themes
      /supr
          /views
              dashboard.php
/public_html
    /assets
        /js
        /css
        /images
        /themes
            /supr
                /js
                /css
                /images
            /kewl_theme2
                /js
                /css
                /images
```

Comment: Well it is possible that's the way PyroCMS is done. I'm just not sure how exactly. I'm looking through documentation and code from the files but there's just so much its hard to understand how its being accomplished.

Comment: @KevinSmith http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?451937-mod_rewrite-Rewrite-outside-of-DocumentRoot

Comment: @KevinSmith of course it's possible. Whether it's better or not is another issue.

Comment: You must understand one thing, pyrocms like codeigniter by default has it's 'point of entrance', the index.php in the root of all files and application and other stuff are subfolders, by moving application out of the folder where index.php is located you restrict ANY access to the files by direct URLs AND apache rewrites, they are reachable only with PHP because php itself is not limited to the current host root folder.

Comment: That's odd because they don't use any mod rewrites that I can see to accomplish this.

Comment: I'm only asking about this because I don't want to just include too many files that I don't really need to accomplish this.

Comment: You won't, they're there just waiting for you to request them whenever you want.

Comment: Why put them on my server taking up space if they are files I don't even need.

Comment: I'm still looking around for how to PyroCMS deals with this and how to use it and just the neccessary files to make it work for me in my application.

Comment: I cannot understand what are you trying to achieve, if you move them to your app/themes directory, they'll be taking up just the same space

Comment: I thought you were talking about using some of the files they use to do this. I have my assets inside the application/themes/supr/assets/ folder.

Comment: They thing is trying to find out how to access them with the asset library and telling it that it needs to look in the current themes folder

Comment: @KevinSmith look, if you have `application` and `public_html` folder in one same parent folder side-by-side and your `document root` for the host is routed to the `public_html` folder, you **CAN NOT** in **ANY** way access any of the assets with the http request located in the `application` folder **BUT** by using http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php **BUT** this way your performace will **DRASTICALLY** decrease. I wanted to point out the key moments, not angry or something :)

Comment: Perhaps you weren't understanding what I was saying but thank you for the effort.